# Search in a <div> for images and get urls back

Tags: javascript

I want to search a `<div>` for images with javascript.

I have this code so far:

```
function geturl(){
    var dividsearch = document.getElementById('uploaded_file');
    var imagesearch = dividsearch.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
    var imagesrc = imagesearch.src;
    alert(imagesrc);
}
```

The problem is that this gives me only the url of the first image back. In my `<div>` can be up to five. How can I get back the urls off all pictures?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: select an image element inside a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876710/javascript-select-an-image-element-inside-a-div)

Comment: Don't explicitly ask for the first item with `[0]`?

Comment: Ever heard of a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're explicitly selecting the first ([0]) element. Try this:

```
var imagesearch = dividsearch.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(var i = 0; i < imagesearch.length; i++){
    alert(imagesearch[i].src);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want all `src` properties, you’d do that with a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
const arrayOfImgSrcs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#uploaded_file img")).map((img) => img.src);
```

Or, using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)’s second argument<sup>1</sup>:

```
const arrayOfImgSrcs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#uploaded_file img"), (img) => img.src);
```

---

<sub>1: Which I’d keep forgetting about, if no [Marty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/699632/marty) existed who would’ve reminded me of it.</sub>

Comment: There's no reason to use `map` like that, `Array.from` accepts a map function as its 2nd argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
var urls =[];
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#uploaded_file img')).forEach(function(img){
    urls.push(img.src);
});
```

Comment: Or just `urls = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#uploaded_file img'), img => img.src)`.

Comment: Or just `urls = [...document.querySelectorAll('#uploaded_file img')].map(e => e.src)`